# MariaDB connector SQL in PowerQuery

Tags: sql, powerbi, mariadb, powerquery

I have been using the ODBC connector in PowerQuery to pull data from MariaDB using custom SQL:

```
Source = Odbc.Query("dsn=jobdb", "SELECT ... From ... WHERE ...")
```

A dedicated connector for MariaDB is now available and I can access data by:

```
Source = MariaDB.Contents("host", "jobdb"),
global_Table = Source {[Name="global",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
```

How do I use custom SQL to pull data from the dedicated MariaDB connector?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I've just come across the same issue but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Does not work, you need to use the ODBC connector for now if you want to write custom queries.